# Two irrational numbers, such that their sum is rational and their product is irrational??

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers

Give Example of two irrational numbers, such that their sum is rational and their product is irrational:

Answer (score 3):

Try $x=1+\pi$ and $y=1-\pi$ then
$$x+y=2$$ and $$xy=1-\pi^2$$

Answer (score 2):

Dumb example: $\pi$ and $-\pi$

Answer (score 1):

Fourth root of two and negative fourth root of two.